# How to read airflow variables into kubernetes pod instance

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I am trying to read airflow variables into my ETL job to populate variables in the curation script. I am using the KubernetesPodOperator. How do I access the metadata database from my k8's pod?

**Error I am getting from airflow:**
ERROR - Unable to retrieve variable from secrets backend (MetastoreBackend). Checking subsequent secrets backend.

This is what I have in main.py for outputting into the console log. I have a key in airflow variables named "AIRFLOW_URL".

```
  from airflow.models import Variable
    AIRFLOW_VAR_AIRFLOW_URL = Variable.get("AIRFLOW_URL")

    logger.info("AIRFLOW_VAR_AIRFLOW_URL: %s", AIRFLOW_VAR_AIRFLOW_URL)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Your DAG can pass them as environment variables to your Pod, using a [template](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) (e.g. `KubernetesPodOperator(... env_vars={"MY_VAR": "{{var.value.my_var}}"}, ...)`).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have a secrets backend set in config without having a secrets backend set up, so Airflow is trying to go there to fetch your variable. [See this link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/secrets-backend/index.html).

Alter your config to remove the `backend` and `backend_kwargs` keys, and it should look at your Airflow variables first.

```
[secrets]
backend =
backend_kwargs =
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, the issue is that they're trying to access airflow variables within a pod, but they cannot do that directly using the method they tried because the pod executing the task is not the same pod that's running airflow. So even with secrets backend configured, they wouldn't be able to do what they are trying.